# Nokia here map localization

Tags: javascript, here-api

I would like to see the countries labels localized, such as Italie in French and Italy in English.  I tried to set the property lang tag in HTML and I also used the
  H.ui.UI.createDefault (mapjs, defaultLayers, cultures), but it translates only the controls and not the map 
I use HERE Maps API for JavaScript 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Link to documentation for createDefaultLayers method](https://developer.here.com/documentation/download/maps_js_html5_nlp/3.0.9.0/Maps%20API%20for%20JavaScript%20v3.0.9.0%20Developer's%20Guide.pdf)

You can use the following code snippet:

```
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
              useCIT: true,
              app_id: 'YOUR_ID',
              app_code: 'YOUR_CODE'
          });

// set lg to chinese
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers(256, 320, 'CHI');

var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'), defaultLayers.normal.map, {
              center: { lat: -8.48331, lng: 115.91348},
              zoom: 4
          });
```

On page 183 you can find the full list of possible languages:
[Map Tile API documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/download/map_tile_nlp/2.1.60.0/Map%20Tile%20API%20v2.1.60.0%20Developer's%20Guide.pdf)